# Extracting the text from the child elements of a div with a class?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have a small Sinatra app:

**app.rb:**

```
get '/' do
  # the first two lines are lifted directly from our previous script
  url = "http://www.nba.com/"
  data = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

  # this line has only be adjusted slightly with the inclusion of an ampersand
  # before concerts.  This creates an instance variable that can be referenced
  # in our display logic (view).
  @headlines = data.css('#nbaAssistSkip')
  @top_stories = data.css('#nbaAssistSkip')

  # this tells sinatra to render the Embedded Ruby template /views/shows.erb
  erb :shows
end
```

**show.erb:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Nokogiri App</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
  <h2><%= @headlines %></h2>
  <p><%= @top_stories %></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Nokogiri, and I was wondering how I can extract the text from the links within `.nbaBreakingNews` div (e.g. Live on NBA...):

[image]

And display them in my template.

(Right now, I only know how to extract text from html tags with classes and IDs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` elements in those sections would be:

```
data.css('.nbaBreakingNewscv a')
```

That means any `a` element that descends from an element with class `nbaBreakingNewscv`. To show the text of those `a` elements you would do:

```
data.css('.nbaBreakingNewscv a').each do |a|
  puts a.text
end
```